# I'm making a music bot with discord.py and I'm having some trouble with the play command

Tags: python, discord.py

The bot has play command that does 3 things it joins the voice channel if it isn't in the voice channel already, it plays songs(obviously) and it stores the songs in a dict called queues if the bot is already playing a song to then play it when the song ends. To do something like this you need the `after` statment on the voiceClients `play` command and it seems to be behaving quit weirdly. I've put some `print` commands to test the bot and it seems that the function that I put on the after statment is firing right away rather then when the song ends, I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong... anyway here's the code:

> this is the function that plays after the play command

```
def continue(ctx):

   queues[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)

   print(f'function continue: {queues}')
    
   if len(queues[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
       return

   Songs.play(ctx=ctx ,song=queues[ctx.guild.id][0])
```

> and here is the play command

```
class Songs(commands.Cog):

   def __init__(self, bot):
       self.client = client


   @commands.command()
   async def play(self, ctx, *, song):

       if ctx.voice_client is None:
           await ctx.message.author.voice.channel.connect()
       else:
           if ctx.voice_client.channel != ctx.message.author.voice.channel:
               await ctx.send('You are not in the same channel as the bot!')
               return
    
       if ctx.guild.id in queues:
           queues[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
       else: 
           queues[ctx.guild.id] = [song]
    
       print(f'function play: {queues}')

       if ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
           await ctx.send('Song added to queue! :thumbsup:')
           return

       ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
       with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
           if musica.startswith('https'):
               info = ydl.extract_info(song, download=False)
               URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
           else:
               info = ydl.extract_info(f'ytsearch:{song}', download=False)
               URL = info['entries'][0]['formats'][0]['url']
    

       FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
       ctx.message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=continue(ctx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you have committed one of the classic Python blunders.  Look at this line:

```
       ctx.message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=continue(ctx))
```

When that line runs, the first thing it's going to do is call your function `continue`.  It will then pass the RESULT of that function call to the `play` function.  You don't want to CALL the function, you want to pass the function object:

```
       ctx.message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=continue)
```

If you really need the context in there, you'll have to use a lambda:

```
       ctx.message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda: continue(ctx))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the final line of your snippet:

```
ctx.message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=continue(ctx))
```

The `after` keyword-parameter expects a callable. You are not giving it that. You are invoking a function `continue` (not a great name for a function, by the way, because you shadow the builtin keyword), and bind the return value to `after`. Since your callable must accept a parameter `ctx`, the quick fix would be to pass in a lambda:

```
after=lambda: continue(ctx)
```